# Можно ли отправить статус 200 с json с сервера Apache?

Tags: apache

Стоит цель сделать простой эхо сервер `apache`.
Например:
запрос - http://localhost:8080/?string=123
ответ - `{string:123}`
Но в гугле не нашел ответа на вопрос, можно ли вообще с сервера `apache` отправлять статус `200` с ответом?
Я могу отправлять только `html` страницы или `php` скрипты?

Comment: Вы можете отправлять строки, раз на то пошло.

Comment: @And можете пожалуйста скинуть ссылку, где описывается как это сделать? буду благодарен

Comment: Apache не является средой для программирования веб-приложений. Не вижу никаких проблем написать php-скрипт для такой задачи

Answer (score 0):

Основное назначение Apache (как и NginX) – быть прокси-сервером, то есть, передавать данные от одного источника к другому (возможно с некоторыми модификациями). Классическое применение:

```
Клиент <-> Apache <-> PHP
                  <-> Статические файлы
```

В этом примере на запросы к статическим файлам (например, CSS, JS, картинки и т.д) Apache считывает данные с диска и возвращает клиенту. А при запросах к PHP файлам вызываются скрипты и возвращается ответ в результате выполнения программы. Такой подход крайне удобен, так как позволяет легко масштабировать систему, заменять отдельные узлы, менять направления запросов и т.д.

---

Соответственно, реализовать "эхо" можно в разных узлах:

1) Можно написать соответствующий скрипт на PHP (или на другом языке, например, Python). Тогда запрос-ответ будут идти так:

```
Клиент -> Apache -> PHP -> Apache -> Клиент
```

2) Можно реализовать в самом Apache, тогда путь будет короче:

```
Клиент -> Apache -> Клиент
```

Лично я с Apache не работал, поэтому не уверен, что есть в нём есть встроенный функционал для этого. Однако на официальном сайте описан модуль **[mod_echo](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_echo.html)** как раз для этой задачи.